Existem artigos que tratam da pronúncia de vogais nasais nos dialetos do Norte-Nordeste?
Andei lendo alguns artigos tratando da natureza das vogais nasais do português brasileiro (PB). Controvérsias à parte, não pude deixar de notar que a maioria deles afirma que os brasileiros pronunciam consoantes nasais entre vogais nasais e consoantes oclusivas. Seguem alguns exemplos:

Campo: /kɐ̃mpu/ ou /kɐ̃ᵐpu/;
Canto: /kɐ̃ntu/ ou /kɐ̃ⁿtu/;
Banco: /bɐ̃ŋku/ ou /bɐ̃ᵑku/.

Já havia notado que muitos falantes das regiões Sul, Sudeste e Centro-Oeste, de fato, pronunciam dessa maneira. Contudo, sou cearense e nunca tinha ouvido (ou ao menos percebido) cearenses ou outras pessoas do Norte ou Nordeste pronunciarem sequências de vogais nasais e oclusivas assim.
Dado que tal pronúncia é perceptível para mim, a ponto de causar estranhamento, parece improvável que ela seja comum na região em que vivo. Olhando alguns artigos mais a fundo, percebi que a maioria, senão todos os autores, eram do eixo Sul-Sudeste, bem como os participantes de seus estudos.
A conclusão a que cheguei é que a pronúncia de consoantes nasais entre vogais nasais e oclusivas é um fenômeno limitado ao Sul-Sudeste-Centro-Oeste. No entanto, não encontrei nenhum artigo tratando das diferenças de pronúncia de vogais nasais entre as variedades do Norte e do Sul do Brasil. Isso suscita-me as seguintes peguntas:

Existem trabalhos que tratam da pronúncia de vogais nasais nos dialetos do Norte do Brasil (como nordestino central, cearense, baiano, recifense, nortista, etc.)?
Se o fenômeno supracitado ocorre nos dialeitos do Norte-Nordeste, porque ele causa estranhamento a mim e a outras pessoas da região?
Se o fenômeno supracitado ocorre apenas no eixo Sul-Sudeste, por que os artigos o classificam como sendo uma propriedade do PB como um todo? É razoável que se faça tal generalização a partir de amostras de alguns falantes de algumas variedades geograficamente concentradas?


Eis um ótimo estudo sobre o falar nordestiino e a nasalidade: https://bdor.sibi.ufrj.br/bitstream/doc/103/1/25%20PDF%20-%20OCR%20-%20RED.pdf
